# Would importing question from private discussion boards be desirable?

Tags: discussion, questions

One of my duties as assistant teacher at the University of British Columbia is to answers questions in the discussion boards of a few Earth Sciences first year courses.

Some of the questions are not in ESSE and are worth of been here. Therefore I wonder: **Would it be recommended/desirable/good for me to "export" those questions with my answers to SE for the benefit of a wider community?**

Answer (score 8):

Yes, but:

- They should be good questions.
- The copyright should be compatible with CC BY-SA 3.0 and you need to respect any other requirements stated by the source.  The answer may be yours, but the question is not.

Comment: Good, and yes. Those are reasonable requirements and shouldn't be a problem. 
Can the "community" be used to post questions? I feel that it is not fair for me to post the question. Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: @CamiloRada You can mark the question as community wiki; in that case nobody will get reputation from votes on the question, nor of any answer.  I'm not sure if there is a way to get reputation on the answers but not on the question.

Comment: I see. And do you think that would be more desirable than creating a fake user for this propose?
The lack of reputation will not encourage others to post an alternative or better answers than mine.

Comment: @CamiloRada A fake user is not a great idea.  You could post it under your own (clearly stating in the question where it's from), then give away the gained reputation to "charity" in the form of a bounty to award exceptional answers (perhaps in particular by new or low-rep users).  Meanwhile you can lobby Stack Exchange to enable CW questions with non-CW answers ;-)  (See [this post on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39351/172266))

Comment: OK, make sense.

Comment: I posted a recent one, let's see how it goes. I will have to dig for good old ones.